# Is there a way for Doxygen to use macros in a function prototype?

Tags: c, doxygen

Say I have this code:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN
#define _at(var) @##var
#else
#define _at(var)
#endif

void _at(near) main (void)
{
return 0;
}
```

Doxygen picks up that function as "_at()". 
Is there a way for it to parse macros (_at(near) in this case to be "") in a function declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to configure doxygen as follows:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = _at(x)=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `MACRO_EXPANSION=yes` in your Doxyfile , as explained [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html)